# Django filter error in GraphQL cookbook example

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I'm currently learning GraphQL via the tutorial on graphene, however I got this error message when I tried to run:

```
python3 manage.py graphql_schema
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in run_from_argv
parser = self.create_parser(argv[0], argv[1])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 355, in create_parser
self.add_arguments(parser)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphene_django/management/commands/graphql_schema.py", line 39, in add_arguments
default=graphene_settings.SCHEMA,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphene_django/settings.py", line 110, in __getattr__
    val = perform_import(val, attr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphene_django/settings.py", line 54, in perform_import
    return import_from_string(val, setting_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphene_django/settings.py", line 68, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/lebeier/Documents/cookbook/schema.py", line 3, in <module>
import ingredients.schema
  File "/Users/lebeier/Documents/cookbook/ingredients/schema.py", line 33, in <module>
class Query(AbstractType):
  File "/Users/lebeier/Documents/cookbook/ingredients/schema.py", line 38, in Query
all_ingredients = DjangoFilterConnectionField(IngredientNode)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphene_django/filter/fields.py", line 20, in __init__
self.filterset_class = get_filterset_class(filterset_class, **meta)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphene_django/filter/utils.py", line 32, in get_filterset_class
return custom_filterset_factory(**meta)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphene_django/filter/filterset.py", line 127, in custom_filterset_factory
    'Meta': meta_class
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/graphene_django/filter/filterset.py", line 55, in __new__
    new_class = super(GrapheneFilterSetMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 224, in __new__
    filters[order_by_field] = new_class.get_ordering_filter(opts, filters)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 375, in get_ordering_filter
    "'order_by' is not compatible with the 'fields' dict syntax. Use OrderingFilter instead."
AssertionError: 'order_by' is not compatible with the 'fields' dict syntax. Use OrderingFilter instead.
```

In my ingredient/schema.py:

```
# cookbook/ingredients/schema.py
from graphene import relay, ObjectType, AbstractType
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType
from graphene_django.filter import DjangoFilterConnectionField

from .models import Category, Ingredient

# Graphene will automatically map the Category model's fields onto the CategoryNode.
# This is configured in the CategoryNode's Meta class (as you can see below)
class CategoryNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        filter_fields = ['name', 'ingredients']
        filter_order_by_field = ['name']
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class IngredientNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        # Allow for some more advanced filtering here
        filter_fields = {
            'name': ['exact', 'icontains', 'istartswith'],
            'notes': ['exact', 'icontains'],
            'category': ['exact'],
            'category__name': ['exact'],
        }
        order_by_field = ['name', 'category__name']
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class Query(AbstractType):
    category = relay.Node.Field(CategoryNode)
    all_categories = DjangoFilterConnectionField(CategoryNode)

    ingredient = relay.Node.Field(IngredientNode)
    all_ingredients = DjangoFilterConnectionField(IngredientNode)
```

django-filter version 0.15.3

I have tried to clone the example from the official graphene repo and it worked fine on python2.7. However in python3.5, the same code failed to work. I am suspecting that something has changed in django-filter that resulted in incompatibility. In python2.7, django-filter version is 0.11.0. Does anyone know how to make it work in 0.15.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a reported as an issue on github and is now fixed: https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/8

Upgrade to graphene 1.1 and you should be good to go.

Comment: oh wait this issue was only closed recently... i will try again

Comment: No, it seems the issue is the filter_fields can no longer contain a dict, and the example uses dicts in RecipeIngredientNode and IngredientNode. You can replace the dicts with lists to comply with the django filters usage: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#the-filter

Comment: Previous docs link is now broken. New link: https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/guide/rest_framework.html#using-the-filter-fields-shortcut

Comment: anyway the graphene 1.1 is not compatible with django filter 1.0.0, I have reported it on graphene-python. but it works for 0.15.3

Answer (score -1):

try install django-filter.

```
pip install django-filter
```